# Javascript: Redirect Based on Form Values

Tags: javascript

I'm making a little quiz for my managers. 
The logic is that they'd respond to each question on a 1-5 scale. I need to sum the responses and then redirect to one page if the responses total < 31 and a different page if they sum > 31.

I borrowed some code from another quiz and modified it a bit because I was thinking there's only one variable needed - the one that stores the running total. But I can't seem to get it to work.

**JScript:**

```
function process()
{
var changeSum = 0;

var f = document.f;
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < f.a.length; i++) if (f.a[i].checked) value = f.a[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.b.length; i++) if (f.b[i].checked) value = f.b[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.c.length; i++) if (f.c[i].checked) value = f.c[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.d.length; i++) if (f.d[i].checked) value = f.d[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.e.length; i++) if (f.e[i].checked) value = f.e[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.f.length; i++) if (f.f[i].checked) value = f.f[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.g.length; i++) if (f.g[i].checked) value = f.g[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.h.length; i++) if (f.h[i].checked) value = f.h[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.j.length; i++) if (f.j[i].checked) value = f.j[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.k.length; i++) if (f.k[i].checked) value = f.k[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

for (i = 0; i < f.l.length; i++) if (f.l[i].checked) value = f.l[i].value;
if (value == "1") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "2") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "3") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "4") { changeSum++; }
if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }

var out = "change-quiz-A";
i = changeSum;

if (changeSum > "31") { out ="change-quiz-B"; }
location.href = out + ".html";
}
function err(msg, url, line)
{
location.href = "error.html";
}
window.onerror = err;
</SCRIPT>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="f">
    <b>How satisfied are the employees with the current state of the business?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Dissatisfied // 5 = Satisfied)</b><br>
    <label for="VD">
        <input type="radio" id="VD" name="a" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D">
        <input type="radio" id="D" name="a" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N">
        <input type="radio" id="N" name="a" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S">
        <input type="radio" id="S" name="a" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS">
        <input type="radio" id="SS" name="a" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>How have employees viewed past changes?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Positively // 5 = Negatively)</b><br>
    <label for="VD1">
        <input type="radio" id="VD1" name="b" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D1">
        <input type="radio" id="D1" name="b" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N1">
        <input type="radio" id="N1" name="b" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S1">
        <input type="radio" id="S1" name="b" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS1">
        <input type="radio" id="SS1" name="b" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <b>Do you have any changes going on now besides this one?</b><br>
        <b>(1 = Very Few Underway // 5 = Everything is Changing!)</b><br>
    <label for="VD2">
        <input type="radio" id="VD2" name="c" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D2">
        <input type="radio" id="D2" name="c" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N2">
        <input type="radio" id="N2" name="c" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S2">
        <input type="radio" id="S2" name="c" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS2">
        <input type="radio" id="SS2" name="c" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>How well were your past changes managed?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Well-Managed // 5 = Poorly Managed</b><br>
    <label for="VD3">
        <input type="radio" id="VD3" name="d" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D3">
        <input type="radio" id="D3" name="d" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N3">
        <input type="radio" id="N3" name="d" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S3">
        <input type="radio" id="S3" name="d" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS3">
        <input type="radio" id="SS3" name="d" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>Is the a shared vision and direction for the organization?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Shared &amp; Unified // 5 = Different &amp; Shifting</b><br>
    <label for="VD4">
        <input type="radio" id="VD4" name="e" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D4">
        <input type="radio" id="D4" name="e" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N4">
        <input type="radio" id="N4" name="e" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S4">
        <input type="radio" id="S4" name="e" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS4">
        <input type="radio" id="SS4" name="e" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>How open are people to new ideas &amp; change?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Open &amp; Receptive // 5 = Closed &amp; Resistant</b><br>
    <label for="VD5">
        <input type="radio" id="VD5" name="f" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D5">
        <input type="radio" id="D5" name="f" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N5">
        <input type="radio" id="N5" name="f" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S5">
        <input type="radio" id="S5" name="f" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS5">
        <input type="radio" id="SS5" name="f" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>What are employees rewarded for?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Embracing Change &amp; Risk-Taking // 5 = Consistency &amp; Predictability</b><br>
    <label for="VD6">
        <input type="radio" id="VD6" name="g" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D6">
        <input type="radio" id="D6" name="g" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N6">
        <input type="radio" id="N6" name="g" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S6">
        <input type="radio" id="S6" name="g" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS6">
        <input type="radio" id="SS6" name="g" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>How is leadership power distributed?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Centralized // 5 = Distributed</b><br>
    <label for="VD7">
        <input type="radio" id="VD7" name="h" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D7">
        <input type="radio" id="D7" name="h" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N7">
        <input type="radio" id="N7" name="h" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S7">
        <input type="radio" id="S7" name="h" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS7">
        <input type="radio" id="SS7" name="h" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>How do <i>senior leaders</i> demonstrate change competency?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Effectively // 5 = Lack Skills &amp; Knowledge</b><br>
    <label for="VD8">
        <input type="radio" id="VD8" name="j" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D8">
        <input type="radio" id="D8" name="j" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N8">
        <input type="radio" id="N8" name="j" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S8">
        <input type="radio" id="S8" name="j" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS8">
        <input type="radio" id="SS8" name="j" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>How do <i>managers</i> demonstrate change competecy?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Effectively // 5 = Lack Skills &amp; Knowledge</b><br>
    <label for="VD9">
        <input type="radio" id="VD9" name="k" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D9">
        <input type="radio" id="D9" name="k" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N9">
        <input type="radio" id="N9" name="k" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S9">
        <input type="radio" id="S9" name="k" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS9">
        <input type="radio" id="SS9" name="k" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <b>How well do <i>employees</i> manage change?</b><br>
    <b>(1 = Very Well // 5 = Poorly</b><br>
    <label for="VD10">
        <input type="radio" id="VD10" name="l" value="1">
            <div>1</div>
    </label>
    <label for="D10">
        <input type="radio" id="D10" name="l" value="2">
            <div>2</div>
    </label>
    <label for="N10">
        <input type="radio" id="N10" name="l" value="3">
            <div>3</div>
    </label>
    <label for="S10">
        <input type="radio" id="S10" name="l" value="4">
            <div>4</div>
    </label>
    <label for="SS10">
        <input type="radio" id="SS10" name="l" value="5">
            <div>5</div>
    </label>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="process()">
</form>
```

Comment: `if (value == "5") { changeSum++; }` -> if value is `5`, increment sum by `1`? That won't add up!

Comment: So the original code that I'm stealing from was Buzzfeed-like. There were 4 variables and each option was weighted, so-to-speak.

Now, I'm guessing I only need one variable to store a running total, but I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/f0rtpcfc/

I would use onsubmit event for that

```
<form name="f" onsubmit='process(event)'>
  ...
  <input type='submit' value="Calculate">
</form>
```

In the javascript use a query selector instead of hardcoding inputs

```
function process(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form   = event.currentTarget;
    var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++){
      if(inputs[i].checked){
        total += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
      }
    }
    console.log(total);
    if(total > 31){
      window.location.href = 'change-quiz-B.html';
    }
    else {
      window.location.href = 'change-quiz-A.html';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm. That didn't seem to work for me. It just redirected back to the quiz page, but kept all the values in the URL a la change-quiz-fiddle.html?a=5&b=5&c=5&d=5&e=5&f=5&g=5&h=5&j=5&k=5&l=5

Answer (score 0):

So this happened to look like more fun than the thing I was supposed to be doing so I had a little play with it. I've approached it form a slightly different way; rather than submitting a form I've added event listeners to the input changes, saved the values in an object and updated the running total as the user progresses.

Oh and I built a function to make the markup so you can just feed it an array of arbitrary questions.

Maybe there are things you can take from it even if it's not perfect for your use case. Either way, amused me for a few minutes :)

**Edit** this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sauntimo/17zvtns2/) of the snippet below might be easier to play with.

```js
arr_questions = [{
  "question_text": "How is this going?",
  "low_val": 1,
  "low_description": "Badly",
  "high_val": 5,
  "high_description": "Kinda okay"
}, {
  "question_text": "Was this a good use of my time?",
  "low_val": 1,
  "low_description": "really not",
  "high_val": 5,
  "high_description": "eh, maybe?"
}, {
  "question_text": "Why do scales always have to be the same?",
  "low_val": 7,
  "low_description": "because",
  "high_val": 13,
  "high_description": "I make my own rules"
}];


obj_questions = {};

function makeQuestion(question_text, low_val, low_description, high_val, high_description) {

  var q_id = 'q' + (Object.keys(obj_questions).length + 1);

  obj_questions[q_id] = {
    "text": question_text,
    "low": low_val,
    "high": high_val,
    "score": 0
  };

  str_html = `<div id="${q_id}" class="question">
   <p class="question-text">${question_text}</p>
    <p class="range-discription">(Where ${low_val} means <em>${low_description}</em> 
    and ${high_val} means <em>${high_description}</em>)</p>`;

  for (i = low_val; i <= high_val; i++) {
    var a_id = q_id + '_a' + i;
    str_html += `<label class="q-label" for="${a_id}">
     <input type="radio" name="${q_id}" id="${a_id}" value="${i}">
      <span class="val_text">${i}</span>
      </label>`;
  }

  str_html += '</div>'
  return str_html;
}

function buildQuestions(arr_qs) {

  var str_html = '';

  arr_qs.forEach(function(obj_q) {
    str_html += makeQuestion(
      obj_q.question_text,
      obj_q.low_val,
      obj_q.low_description,
      obj_q.high_val,
      obj_q.high_description
    );
  });

  return str_html;
}

function addEventHandlers() {
  var arr_targets = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
  for (i = 0; i < arr_targets.length; i++) {
    arr_targets[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      scoreChange(this.name, this.value);
    });
  }
}

function scoreChange(question, value) {
  obj_questions[question].score = parseInt(value, 10);
  var total = 0;
  var possible = 0;

  for (var key in obj_questions) {
    total += obj_questions[key].score;
    possible += obj_questions[key].high;
  }

  var percent = Math.round((total / possible) * 100, 1);

  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('possible').innerHTML = possible;
  document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = percent;

  document.getElementsByClassName('total')[0].classList.remove('hidden');
}

(function init() {
  var str_html = buildQuestions(arr_questions);
  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName('questions')[0].innerHTML = str_html;
  addEventHandlers();
})();
```

```css
.container {
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.question,
.total {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.question-text {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.q-label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.total p {
  margin: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="questions"></div>
  <div class="total hidden">
    <p class="running-total">The current total is: <span id="total">0</span> out of <span id="possible">0</span> or, <span id="percent">0</span>%.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, this is probably better for what I need! My little quiz is just like a Comso mag type thing, so it doesn't really need to redirect. It just needs to show the total.

Comment: Aw, well, I'm glad. I just edited to percentage in the total FWIW. Feel free to ask about any thing if it doesn't make sense and if it helps and you want to mark it as accepted that would obviously be okay too ;)

Comment: OK, I don't know what's happening, but I literally copied and pasted what you have into a blank file and nothing happens when I load -- I just get a blank page.

Comment: Did you copy the html mark up too? It needs to be there for the js to find and add things to. Were there any errors in the console? Does your environment support ES6 string interpolation? `text and ${vbl} together`

Comment: Here's the error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: Sounds like it can't find the html. Did you add the html I had in my answer to yours? If it can't find it, it won't be able to add anything to it.

Comment: Yes sir. I don't get it.

Comment: Which line is failing? Which value is undefined? Maybe a selector is wrong. Can you select the same element in your browser dev console?